# How to define a Constant Address (Publickey) in Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

So, I want one function to be accessible to the only contract owner. So can I hard code that address and I want my rent sol to go back to that account when that account closes?

Is there a way to get the program's upgrade authority or the program's deployer in the contract itself?

If there is no way, is Any other optimal way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the macro `pubkey!` from `use solana_program::pubkey;`

Here's an example of only allowing one pubkey to call an instruction:

```
#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;

    const OWNER: Pubkey = pubkey!("766Mum7jSmvDPpvcKrY7WV4A69Jk6Xhgps958RDQgYcq");

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        if ctx.accounts.signer.key() != OWNER {
            return Err(error!(ErrorCode::Unauthorized));
        }
        
        ctx.accounts.new_account.data = data;
        msg!("Changed data to: {}!", data); // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

You can see a complete example on Playground here: https://beta.solpg.io/6310e05288a7fca897ad7d0f

If you change the `pubkey!` to your playground wallet address (shown at the bottom of the UI) and deploy, you'll be able to call that `initialize` instruction from the test UI.

If you change the `pubkey!` in the code and re-deploy (or change the `signer` in the instruction call) it'll fail with the `Unauthorized` message.

Answer (score 3):

A neat way to initialize constant Pubkeys in an organized way.

**Lib.rs**

```
// Program Id
declare_id!("e8zpvHybTbjMjoDR7CWjBUj1ttxQwRMUebhAf2z52ba");

mod pubkeys {
    use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

    // User Publickey
    pub mod user {
        use super::*;
        declare_id!("a8zpvHybTbjMjoDR7CWjBUj1ttxQwRMUebhAf2z5aaa");
    }

    // Vault Publickey
    pub mod vault {
        use super::*;
        declare_id!("b8zpvHybTbjMjoDR7CWjBUj1ttxQwRMUebhAf2z5bbb");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
use crate::*;

msg!("{}", ID)                   // prints Program Id
msg!("{}", pubkeys::user::ID);   // user User Address
msg!("{}", pubkeys::vault::ID);  // vault Vault Address
```